# Open neutral reading

Tags: electrical, wiring

Using a three prong outlet tester I found all the outlets on a circuit show open neutral but the outlets all work. Any ideas?

Comment: On another circuit does the outlet tester read okay?

Answer (score 2):

For any suspected open wire, the steps are the same:

1. Shut off the circuit.
2. Remove the outlet cover, unscrew it, and pull it out to inspect the wire connections to the outlet.  Fix anything wrong.  Push it back in and screw the outlet back in place.  I defer replacing the cover to facilitate probing in place with a voltmeter if needed.
3. If it is acceptable **or** you are not extremely confident of being able to avoid the exposed contacts, switch off the main breaker.
4. Open the service panel by removing the cover to inspect the wiring inside.  Test every mechanical connection by grabbing each wire near the end and wiggling **firmly** to verify a secure connection.  Repeat for every end in a circuit breaker, every ground wire, and every neutral wire.
5. If you still can't find the problem, you may have to check every outlet on the circuit between the panel and the misbehaving outlet.  If you don't know the sequence, just check all of them.  Occasionally there may be wall switch boxes which contain a junction for the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. The neutral is open but the ground is connect to the neutral somewhere. Or the receptacles area simply miswired. So the outlets are using the ground AS the neutral. That is why they still work. This is a violation of the National Electrical Code and is potentially dangerous since you have current on the ground wire while the circuit is in use. Check to see that the receptacles are wired properly.